# Determine the minimum of:$\frac{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)}}{a+b+c+d},\text{ if }a,b,c,d>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Determine the minimum of:$\frac{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)}}{a+b+c+d}$, if $a,b,c,d>0$

I tried partial derivatives of the unction and also its natural log aI came up with system of equation that is not easy to solve. Using AM GM easily you can show the given fraction is greater or equal than 1

Comment: AM-GM says greater than or equal to 1, setting $a=b=c=d=1$ obtains this as a value, hence minimum is 1

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst That’s an AM-GM I would like to see, as I can quite easily get values less than $1$ from the above.  In fact $\dfrac4{3\sqrt3}$ is possible.

Comment: I just assumed Keon had proved it!

Comment: but do post any new minima you find

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake

Comment: Consider the restricted domain with $a=b=c=d=x$, then you get $(1+x^2)^2/(4x)$ to minimise, which is easy.  Of course this does not guarantee its the min on original domain, which still needs to be proved.

Comment: I proved LS>=4sqrt(abcd)/(a+b+c+d) I thought num is GM."My mistake." which may help

Comment: Is the f(a,b,c,d) a convex function

Comment: Grad(f)=0 at a=b=c=d=1/sqrt(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{x}{\sqrt3},$ $b=\frac{y}{\sqrt3},$ $c=\frac{z}{\sqrt3}$ and $d=\frac{t}{\sqrt3}$.

Thus, by C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1)(d^2+1)}}{a+b+c+d}=\frac{\sqrt{(x^2+3)(y^2+3)(z^2+3)(t^2+3)}}{9(a+b+c+d)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\sqrt{2((x+y)^2+4)\cdot2(4+(z+t)^2)}}{9(a+b+c+d)}\geq\frac{2(2(x+y)+2(y+t))}{9(a+b+c+d)}=\frac{4}{3\sqrt3}.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{\sqrt3},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

I used the following inequality:
$$(x^2+3)(y^2+3)\geq2((x+y)^2+4),$$ which is
$$(xy-1)^2+(x-y)^2\geq0.$$